# Update query on Temporary table in LINQ with concatenation operation

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, stored-procedures

I am trying to convert stored procs into LINQ using linqpad. I have folllowing sql query which i want to convert to LINQ

```
 UPDATE @tempTable
 SET fullname = (p.LastName + ', ' + ISNULL(p.FirstName, ''))
 FROM @tempTable t, Table1 i, table2 p
  WHERE r.ID = i.ID
  AND i.ID = p.ID
```

How it can be done in LINQ? I am just converting SP's to LINQ without using entity framework. Does it really necessary to use entity framework?

Comment: It's not necessary but you're essentially going to have to load the data independently and then query it; whereas if this table had a strongly-typed model (Linq2SQL, or EntityFramework) you could use Linq directly against the source. I don't know that it's possible otherwise.

Comment: Hey Grant, Thanks for such a quick response. I am new to LINQ. I am having hard figuring out how to write update query on temporary tables in LINQ Can you please tell me how it can be done?